# Mounted (external) Linux, change date

Tags: date, timestamps

I created a daemon-bash-script on a Debian, which copies an `.img` to an external disk. The script copies the `.img` with `dd` to the external disk and afterward it mounts the disk to check the filesystem.

Is there a possibility to change the date and time in a file somewhere? My problem is that after the first boot (without an internet link) the year is in 2033.

I tried to change the timestamp in `/etc/adjtime`. But after a reboot, it only set's back to 2033:

```
0.000000 2001162716 0.000000
2001162716
UTC
```

Thanks :)

**EDIT 1**

I just found out that my Alix has two different dates:

```
~# hwclock
Sat Jan  1 01:01:04 2000  -0.521995 seconds
~# date
Tue May 31 20:49:59 CEST 2033
```

How's that possible?

Comment: What's your BIOS date ?

Comment: Hmm. I'm using a ALIX board [link](https://clutterbox.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/alix6b2.jpg). I don't know how to enter the BIOS. But in fact, I'm using like 50 of them, so entering every BIOS to change the date is probably not the best solution :)

Comment: That value in `adjtime` is not used to set the time. Normally, at boot the kernel discovers the hardware rtc device, reads it and sets the system time to that value. `cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/hctosys` should be 1 if it did this. Use `hwclock` to read the rtc.  Perhaps your board doesnt have an rtc, or no battery?

Comment: Probably it has a battery, or at least is a tiny BIOS (which I found out right now) in the ROM saved. But not that many functions, like no function for date/time. The BIOS settings are [these](https://s12.postimg.io/50zsu8ztp/screenshot.png)

Comment: You should probably add debian package fake-hwclock to your setup. It is supposed to handle boards with no battery-backed rtc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @meuh I installed

```
fake-hwclock
```

on my system and now I can write date-time into a config file

```
/etc/fake-hwclock.data
```

and the system boots with that time.